# Phantom entries in ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms

So I am using xamarin.forms for android and IOS app my main view is calendar and every day has list TodayEnty of ServerModel, data i get from server. Inside of ListView i have StackLayout with Bindable.Layout that displays whole list inside each day and problem is that when scrolling copies appear of days appear in ListView.
This is screen record of what problem looks like : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PN8_nyvg-uDipVc516PXb23ztThHOAiN/view?usp=sharing

The calendar is populated with mock data and what is seen at 16th secound of video is all that is in whole mont in all of the day. So as you can see as the video goes on i have more and more entries in ListView taht don't acctualy exist in my list in ViewModel

I really have no idea what could cause this problem since I am very new to xamarin.forms.

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedMonth.MonthDays}" x:Name="MyDaysListView">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Text="{Binding DayNum}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding DayName}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
                            <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding TodayEntry}" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding WorkOrder}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate> 
        </ListView>
```

Comment: what's your XF version ?

Answer (score 0):

There may be an issue with view recycling and the `BindableLayout`...

What I would try to do:

1. See if set CachingStrategy="RetainElement" solves the issue, but it will consume more memory (but not that much since you have 30 elements max)
2. If it doesn't, I would build the today entries programmatically with the `OnBindingContextChanged` event of the `ViewCell`
3. You could also use the `CollectionView` instead of the `ListView`, see if it works better
4. Or if you want a production readay component, you could use the `HorizontalListView`, https://github.com/roubachof/Sharpnado.Presentation.Forms#grid-Layout, with `Layout=Grid and ColumnCount=1`

Comment: CachingStrategy="RetainElement" and CollectionView gave no result, I will try OnBindingContextChanged, do you have any example of how to use this since i am new to xamarin.forms?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-cell-appearance#binding-context-changes for custom ViewCell, and this https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/70210/how-do-i-use-the-bindingcontext-property-of-viewcell-in-the-xaml for vanilla ones.